# different pages in a canvas game

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

**The Problem**

I am creating a game using the HTML5 Canvas, the game has a main menu, the main menu has multiple buttons for you to choose. I am finding it difficult and confusing how I would, for example if the user presses the 'Play' button, to show the game. Here is an image of the main menu:

[image: Main menu of game.]

**The Question**

The question is how would I get from this page to another in my game?

[image]

I think you get the idea. I deliberately created the menu using the canvas, I know I could of made the menu using HTML for example but I cant as this is an example for students of what Canvas can do, whats good and bad etc.

**The Code**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sean Coyne</title>
</head>
<body onload="start_game()">
<body>
    <div style id="canvas">
        <canvas id="myCanvas" style="border:5px solid #410b11" height="320" width="480">
            <p>Your browser does not support HTML5!</p>
        </canvas>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            //Referencing the canvas
            var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            var width = canvas.getAttribute('width');
            var height = canvas.getAttribute('height');

            //Finding the position of the mouse
            var mouseX;
            var mouseY;

            //Images
            var bgImage = new Image();
            var logoImage = new Image();
            var playImage = new Image();
            var instructImage = new Image();
            var settingsImage = new Image();
            var aboutImage = new Image();
            var peaceImage = new Image();

            var backgroundY = 0;
            var speed = 1;

            //Arrays below used for mouse over function
            var buttonX = [130,110,130,160];
            var buttonY = [100,140,180,220];
            var buttonWidth = [96,260,182,160];
            var buttonHeight = [40,40,40,40];

            var peaceX = [0,0];
            var peaceY = [0,0];
            var peaceWidth = 35;
            var peaceHeight = 35;

            var peaceVisible = false;
            var peaceSize = peaceWidth;
            var peaceRotate = 0;

            var frames = 30;
            var timerId = 0;
            var fadeId = 0;
            var time = 0.0;

            peaceImage.src = "Images/peace.png";
            bgImage.onload = function(){
                context.drawImage(bgImage, 0, backgroundY);
            };
            bgImage.src = "Images/background.png";
            logoImage.onload = function(){
                context.drawImage(logoImage, 50, -10);
            }
            logoImage.src = "Images/logo.png";
            playImage.onload = function(){
                context.drawImage(playImage, buttonX[0], buttonY[0]);
            }
            playImage.src = "Images/play.png";
            instructImage.onload = function(){
                context.drawImage(instructImage, buttonX[1], buttonY[1]);
            }
            instructImage.src = "Images/instructions.png";
            settingsImage.onload = function(){
                context.drawImage(settingsImage, buttonX[2], buttonY[2]);
            }
            settingsImage.src = "Images/settings.png";
            aboutImage.onload = function(){
                context.drawImage(aboutImage, buttonX[3], buttonY[3]);
            }
            aboutImage.src = "Images/about.png";

            timerId = setInterval("update()", 1000/frames);

            canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", checkPos);
            canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", checkClick);

            function update() {
                clear();
                move();
                draw();
            }
            function clear() {
                context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
            }
            function move(){
                backgroundY -= speed;
                if(backgroundY == -1 * height){
                    backgroundY = 0;
                }
                if(peaceSize == peaceWidth){
                    peaceRotate = -1;
                }
                if(peaceSize == 0){
                    peaceRotate = 1;
                }
                peaceSize += peaceRotate;
            }


            function draw(){
                context.drawImage(bgImage, 0, backgroundY);
                context.drawImage(logoImage, 50,-10);
                context.drawImage(playImage, buttonX[1], buttonY[0]);
                context.drawImage(instructImage, buttonX[2], buttonY[1]);
                context.drawImage(settingsImage, buttonX[2], buttonY[2]);
                context.drawImage(aboutImage, buttonX[3], buttonY[3]);
                    if(peaceVisible == true){
                    context.drawImage(peaceImage, peaceX[0] - (peaceSize/2), peaceY[0], peaceSize, peaceHeight);
                    context.drawImage(peaceImage, peaceX[2] - (peaceSize/2), peaceY[2], peaceSize, peaceHeight);
                }
            }

            function checkPos(mouseEvent){
                if(mouseEvent.pageX || mouseEvent.pageY == 0){
                    mouseX = mouseEvent.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
                    mouseY = mouseEvent.pageY - this.offsetTop;
                }else if(mouseEvent.offsetX || mouseEvent.offsetY == 0){
                    mouseX = mouseEvent.offsetX;
                    mouseY = mouseEvent.offsetY;
                }
                for(i = 0; i < buttonX.length; i++){
                    if(mouseX > buttonX[i] && mouseX < buttonX[i] + buttonWidth[i]){
                        if(mouseY > buttonY[i] && mouseY < buttonY[i] + buttonHeight[i]){
                            peaceVisible = true;
                            peaceX[0] = buttonX[i] - (peaceWidth/2) - 2;
                            peaceY[0] = buttonY[i] + 2;
                            peaceX[1] = buttonX[i] + buttonWidth[i] + (peaceWidth/2); 
                            peaceY[1] = buttonY[i] + 2;
                        }
                    }else{
                        peaceVisible = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            function checkClick(mouseEvent){
                for(i = 0; i < buttonX.length; i++){
                    if(mouseX > buttonX[i] && mouseX < buttonX[i] + buttonWidth[i]){
                        if(mouseY > buttonY[i] && mouseY < buttonY[i] + buttonHeight[i]){
                            fadeId = setInterval("fadeOut()", 1000/frames);
                            clearInterval(timerId);
                            canvas.removeEventListener("mousemove", checkPos);
                            canvas.removeEventListener("mouseup", checkClick);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            function fadeOut(){
                context.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0, 0.2)";
                context.fillRect (0, 0, width, height);
                time += 0.1;
                if(time >= 2){
                    clearInterval(fadeId);
                    time = 0;
                    timerId = setInterval("update()", 1000/frames);
                    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", checkPos);
                    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", checkClick);
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd simply replace the current canva with the right one depending on the user's choice... ?

Comment: So use multiple canvas', depending on what the user chooses, show that canvas?

Comment: Debugging help questions require a [mcve] as per the [help]. Your code is not minimal. Please [edit] your question to make sure that your code is Minimal (only the code necessary to reproduce your issue in your question), Complete (users do not need anything else to reproduce your issue), and Verifiable (the provided code does reproduce the exact issue you are facing). As it is your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Note that this is also a common [downvote reason](http://idownvotedyoubecause.com/so/TooMuchCode).

Comment: You can either just store state of the screen/game and update/draw according to that on the same canvas. Or swap out different canvas elements. Or just do the menu, etc, with HTML (which I would argue is the best way to do your menus, HTML is best for textual markup, no need to reinvent the wheel here).

Comment: Thanks ManoDestra, I did state why im not using html for the menu but i know what you mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I usually do is have a switch statement inside the `draw` loop, and a state variable which holds the current game state (menu, playing, etc...).

Then, based on the current game state you only draw the objects required for the current scene.

Something like this:

```
var STATES = { 
  Menu: 0,
  PauseMenu: 1,
  Playing: 2
};
var currentState = STATES.Menu;
...
function draw() {
  switch(currentState) {
    case STATES.Menu:
      // Draw buttons, etc..
    break;
    case STATES.Playing:
      // Draw the game screen, the player, etc...
    break;
  }
}
```

When the user presses the `Play` button the only thing you have to do is:

```
function onPlayButtonClick() {
   currentState = STATES.Playing;
   // Starting the next frame the new state will be "magically" drawn
}
```

If you don't like the switch statement, you can create a `State` class that has a `draw` method. Then you can simply create new states, each with it's own drawing method and in the main draw loop only call the draw method of the current state.

Same goes for the `update` function, each state has it's own update function (in the main menu you update buttons or animate things, while playing the game you update the game world and run your physics). So, based on the current state your `update` function is actually different. It's up to you how you structure your code and how you call different functions based on the current state.

Comment: +1, this is the way to go. Combine this with a game loop (update, render, etc) and this is immensely powerful. Edit: I see you've already updated your answer to include this, nvm =)

Comment: Now ive just got to get my head round implementing this, atleast ive got all day haha!

Comment: @RushFan2112 It really is not as complicated as you think when you get used to it! When building your game, use a game loop consisting of the Update() and Draw() methods. Inside update, keep track of the changing states of the game. In the Draw() method, check what the current state is before rendering to the canvas. This is quite an in-depth tutorial, but ive it a look - it's helpful! Edit: http://blog.sklambert.com/html5-game-tutorial-game-ui-canvas-vs-dom/

Comment: @Lewis Thanks for the tutorial, will take a look right away! It all makes so much sense in my head but Im just finding it hard to do, more practice and il be fine im sure!

Answer (score 1):

In each text option, you should create a smaller Canvas, only with the option text and add a 'click' event with the callbacks.

Tip: You don't need another page, just erase the main canvas and draw what you want.

Comment: So create 4 canvas' for each option in the menu?

Comment: Yes, one canvas for each option, and then add the event handler.